# Google spreadsheets translate returns double quotes

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I am using GoogleTranslate() function to translate one language to another in Google spreadsheets. 
I have a sentence in one (known) language at column A1 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet' and i want the translation of it in English at column B1. 
so i used this:

```
=GoogleTranslate(A1, "li", "en")
```

The result is:

```
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet".
```

There is double quotes now.
I want the translation to be with single quote (like before),
I found its Google's bug (yes, i said it Google's bug lol).
So the solution maybe in within regular expression or something else...

How can I replace the  double quotes (in the being and the end only) of the translated sentence in Google spreadsheets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the docs it looks like Google Spreadsheets only allows you to *search* with regex and not replace, but in case you actually can:

```
Find: "(.*?)"
Replace: '\1'
```

You can of course also do this with some other program using the same regexen.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like...

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A2,"''","'")
```

This (perhaps overly-simple?) function will replace two adjacent single quotes with one single quote. So you could combine them and end up with:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(GoogleTranslate(A1, "li", "en"),"''","'")
```

It's not the most elegant, but I think it should work...

Answer (score 0):

it seems `li` is no longer supported:

[image]

see the list of supported locales at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73767720/5632629