# How can I use DETECTLANGUAGE and GOOGLETRANSLATE formula in one cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-translate

I have a google sheets file and I want to use DETECTLANGUAGE to detect the language and GOOGLETRANSLATE formula to translate the language detected to English in one cell

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!

Comment: Your question can be greatly improved if you add input table and expected output table to the question. [Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) are a better alternative than spreadsheets to show your data structure. If you share spreadsheets, make sure to also add images of your sheet to avoid closure of your question, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Answer (score 1):

After a research I found that I can use "auto" to auto-detect the language.so it will be like that GOOGLETRANSLATE(text, [AUTO, target_language])

Comment: watch out for AUTO mode. it is not always supported: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73767720/5632629