# Sorting and showing specific colums

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have data that I want to sort in my google sheets; but I want to show only specific columns and not others.

Here's an example :

| Name | Type | HP | ATK |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Hero1 | type1 | 10 | 5 |
| Hero2 | type1 | 9 | 8 |
| Hero3 | type2 | [null] | 7 |
| Hero4 | type2 | 11 | 6 |

After a `=SORT()` in an other sheet; I'd like to have something like this :

| Name | HP |
| --- | --- |
| Hero4 | 11 |
| Hero1 | 10 |
| Hero2 | 9 |

And with an other `=SORT()` have this :

| Name | ATK |
| --- | --- |
| Hero2 | 8 |
| Hero3 | 7 |
| Hero4 | 6 |
| Hero1 | 5 |

I tried with `FILTER()` But I can't manage to get rid of the `Type` column

Of course I don't want to modify the first table

But I could use sorted tables containing only the name and not wathever value was used to sort them

***EDIT :***
[image: Test image]

Comment: Can try `=FILTER(SORT(A2:D,3,0),{1,0,1,0})`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a virtual array `{A2:A,D2:D}` and use

```
=SORT({A2:A,D2:D},2,0)
```

or even

```
=SORT({A2:A,C2:C},2,0)
```

*(**Do adjust** the formula according to your ranges and locale)*

In your case it would be:

```
=SORT({A2:A\D2:D};2;0)
```

[image]

Comment: Tried it, It put me column A then B in the same column but not sorted

Comment: *"It put me column A then B in the same column"*. You probably need `;`

Comment: Nope, exact same result

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1e6FDK9_kbZU6RvGFxHTVRHLsC3mMdaUgu77JfgxvqII/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Your sheet is private. Please make it public.

Comment: It's now public

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: Still the same problem

Comment: I cannot find an issue in our end. Try `=QUERY(SORT({A2:A\C2:C};2;0);"where Col2 is not null")`

Comment: @marikamitsos you are [Anonymous Moose](https://i.imgur.com/c2J35ae.png) :) ?

Answer (score 2):

**One**

```
=QUERY({A:D};"Select Col1,Col4 where Col1 <> '' Order by Col4 desc";1)
```

**Two**

```
=QUERY({A:D};"Select Col1,Col3 where Col1 <> '' Order by Col3 desc";1)
```

[image]

[**`QUERY`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en)

Comment: Query is giant function in gs.

Comment: Why not `=QUERY(A:D,"Select A,D Order by D DESC",1)`?

Comment: So he could paste another formula in the refrence directly, and he lern `{}` arrys from it also.

Comment: Then combine two query into one array so that op no need to write two function separately.

Comment: To quote the OP *`After a =SORT() in an other sheet;`* and *`And with an other =SORT() have this :...`* he did't specify, suggest it in your answer maybe he wants it that way.

Comment: Works pretty well, but in my original table, I have some cell with no value, is it possible to exclude any valu that is null ? ( Made an edit to the question)

Comment: @Neo the answer is updated

Comment: It doesn' work; I have an error telling me no result found

Comment: Can you share what you adjusted? or a screenshot

Comment: Its a Local issue `;` in your locsl instead of comma `,`  in US local

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248409/discussion-between-neo-and-osm).

Comment: @Neo Test it now its working in your sheet

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=SORT(FILTER({A2:A\C2:C}; C2:C<>""); 2; )
```

[image]

and:

```
=SORT(FILTER({A2:A\D2:D}; D2:D<>""); 2; )
```

[image]

pros: SORT with FILTER is faster and more reliable than QUERY that can eat your data

also, see how to convert commas to semicolons: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73767720/5632629