# What datetime format is this 2022-04-05T12:39:34.579775Z and how to convert to US date time format?

Tags: date, datetime, google-sheets, timezone, iso8601

What datetime format is this 2022-04-05T12:39:34.579775Z and how to convert to US date time format but in GMT timezone with a formula in Google Sheets when it appears in A1 and I want to return correct format in b1?

Comment: That's the international ISO format.

Comment: answer updated..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

try:

```
=SUM(SPLIT(A1, "TZ"))
```

[image]

[image]

see: [locale differences in google sheets (documentation missing pages)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73767719/5632629)

and: [https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/iso-time.html](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/%7Emgk25/iso-time.html)

and: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Times

---

---

### update:

as mentioned `Z` stands for UTC

UTC ≈ GMT see: https://24timezones.com/gmt-vs-utc

The United States has 6 timezones:

[image]

so for example, if you reside in Pacific Time Zone you are in UTC-7

see map: https://www.timeanddate.com/time/map/

therefore your:

```
2022-04-05T12:39:34.579775Z
```

is actually equal to:

```
4/5/2022 5:39:34.579775
```

and the formula is:

```
=SUM(SPLIT(A1, "TZ", "-7:00"))
```

[image]

and with milliseconds:

```
=TEXT(SUM(SPLIT(A1, "TZ"), "-7:00"), "m/d/e h:mm:ss.000")
```

[image]

or with extra precision:

```
 =TEXT(SUM(SPLIT(A1, "TZ"), "-7:00"), "m/d/e h:mm:ss")&REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "(\.\d+)")
```

[image]

and don't forget to account for the Daylight Saving system!

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint that would require script

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime($yourDate));
```

Comment: Thanks Annisa, I'm not quite sure how to make this work though