# Unpivot data table with column groups

Tags: google-sheets, syntax, google-sheets-formula, unpivot, google-query-language

My data is in this format:

| A | B | C | D | E | F | G |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| USER1 | A-DATA1 | A-DATA2 | A-DATA3 | B-DATA1 | B-DATA2 | B-DATA3 |
| USER2 | A-DATA1 | A-DATA2 | A-DATA3 | B-DATA1 | B-DATA2 | B-DATA3 |

The desired results would look like this:

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| USER1 | A-DATA1 | A-DATA2 | A-DATA3 |
| USER1 | B-DATA1 | B-DATA2 | B-DATA3 |
| USER2 | A-DATA1 | A-DATA2 | A-DATA3 |
| USER2 | B-DATA1 | B-DATA2 | B-DATA3 |

I test many things, with INDEX - ROW - COLUMN - TRANSPOSE
but I never get the desired result... If you have a great idea, that would be super helpful.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See [How much research effort is expected of stackoverflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Comment: Hello @player0 here a demo link https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KbV7fwhtThQ7bLZcbISKUEFSUwvmXkwL0LKG9LP0GwU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: answer updated..

Comment: see how to convert separators from comma to semicolon: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73767719/5632629

Comment: Thank you very much, it's absolutely perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY({A3:D; A3:A\ E3:G}; "where Col1 is not null order by Col1"; )
```

[image]

Comment: Hey thanks, looks brillant, but i have #ERROR s what i'm missing ? I put the table in edit mode https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KbV7fwhtThQ7bLZcbISKUEFSUwvmXkwL0LKG9LP0GwU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @JulienFunken use: `=QUERY({A3:D; A3:A\ E3:G}; "where Col1 is not null order by Col1"; )`

Comment: it's real cool, thanks, and if i want more serie of data - like C-DATA .. how i can add a new range ?
google sheet update : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KbV7fwhtThQ7bLZcbISKUEFSUwvmXkwL0LKG9LP0GwU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @JulienFunken you will just add `; A3:A\ H3:J` see your sheet...