# VLookup Multiple Criteria Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup

Can somebody help me what's wrong with this formula?
(If I replace semicolons by comas I get an parsing error)
Thanks in advance!

The formula:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(E2&F2;{A:A&B:B;C:C};2;0))`

[image]

Comment: In situations like this I usually create a combined lookup column `=A2&B2` then vlookup on that instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of

```
A:A&B:B; C:C
```

use

```
A:A&B:B\ C:C
```

for more info see: [locale differences in google sheets (documentation missing pages)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73767719/5632629)

Comment: Wow, thanks! Never saw this somewhere but that's the soultion