# Formula Parse Error Google Sheets using IF function

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets

I was trying to count checkboxes and I saw some tutorials for the formula
it was like this

```
=SUM(countif(B1:B8, TRUE))
```

it resulted in an error instead with "formula parse error"

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=SUM(COUNTIF(B1:B8; TRUE))
```

see: [stackoverflow.com/questions/73767719/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73767719/locale-differences-in-google-sheets-documentation-missing-pages)

[image]