# How can I convert one dataframe in google sheets into another format

Tags: dataframe, if-statement, google-sheets, lambda, google-query-language

The format the spreadsheet is currently in is.

| Date | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1/1/22 | Joe schmoe |
| 1/1/22 | Jill will |
| 1/2/22 | Joe schmoe |
| 1/2/22 | Bob Flob |

For each date. I have a variable number of names.

I would like the format to be

| Name | 1/1/22 | 1/2/22 | 1/3/22 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Joe schmoe | Present | Present | Present |
| Jill will | Present | absent | absent |
| Bob Flob | absent | Present | Present |

How can I do this in google sheets?
The first sheet is changing everyday.
Thanks

I have tried to use a for loop and an if loop in spreadsheets and can't figure out what I need to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY(A:B, "select B,count(B) where B is not null group by B pivot A", 1)
```

[image]

or:

```
=INDEX(LAMBDA(x, IF(x="", "absent", IF((x>0)*(x<40000), "present", x)))
 (QUERY(A:B, "select B,count(B) where B is not null group by B pivot A", 1)))
```

[image]

or:

```
=INDEX(LAMBDA(x, IF(x="", "absent", IF((x>0)*(x<40000), "present", TEXT(x, "d/m/yy"))))
 (QUERY(A:B, "select B,count(B) where B is not null group by B pivot A", 1)))
```

[image]

Comment: How would I do this if I was pulling the data from another sheet. 
Hopefully this isn't really dumb. But I want the data into a new spreadsheet

Comment: II am getting invalid call to non-function. When I try any of these... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Also my dates include times as well. How do I trim that and make my columns just by dates rather than date and time

Comment: @JeredKarr for another sheet change `A:B` to `'Sheet1'!A:B` where `Sheet1` is name of your sheet. if your dates contain time change `A:B` to `{INT(A:A), B:B}` to trim off the time

Comment: =INDEX(LAMBDA(x, IF(x="", "absent", IF((x>0)*(x<40000), "present", TEXT(x, "d/m/yy"))))
 (QUERY('Form Responses 1'!{A:A, B:B}, "select B,count(B) where B is not null group by B pivot A", 1)))

This doesn't work there is a parse error

Comment: I want to combine 'Sheet1'!A:B with {INT(A:A), B:B}

Comment: @JeredKarr try: `=INDEX(LAMBDA(x, IF(x="", "absent", IF((x>0)*(x<40000), "present", TEXT(x, "d/m/yy")))) (QUERY({'Sheet1'!A:B; {INT(A:A), B:B}}, "select Col2,count(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col2 pivot Col1", 1))) `

Comment: =Sept!A2;{INT(A2)} Why doesn't this work?

Comment: I tried it on the actual dataset and it is making a unique column for each time stamp instead of grouping each date into the a column. Not sure what the problem is. When I ran it on my test google form rather than the actual one it worked and grouped them into the dates. What could be the differences in the two forms? Also why can I @player0

Comment: @JeredKarr should be `={Sept!A2; {INT(A2)}}`  or `={Sept!A2; INT(A2)}` see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73767720/5632629

Comment: I am still having troubles with this code. It isn't grouping the days and instead is keeping them separated by the time so that each time is a separate column...

Comment: @JeredKarr if you share some sample sheet with the issue I could check it out

Comment: how do I share a sample sheet?