# Converting google form responses into attendance spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

How can I reformat a spreadsheet from a Google Form into a functional attendance spreadsheet?

I have tried `VLOOKUP` and other `IF` statements and it is getting above my head.

---

### My Goal

***How google form is inputting data into spreadsheet:***
[image]

***How I want a spreadsheet formatted to make an attendance form:***
[image]

---

Comment: Query function may help. Share a sample google-sheet link. You must specify late time.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74467870/how-can-i-convert-one-dataframe-in-google-sheets-into-another-format/74467951?noredirect=1#comment131492712_74467951

I actually asked this question last year. I just saw that someone had answered and there answer works pretty good. I guess I added the idea of late for this version. Not sure how much harder that makes this. Late time in this example is 10:00 AM

Comment: Are you looking to have single formula to convert the entire spreadsheet from a Google Form responses into a different attendance spreadsheet? OR are you considering alternative solution like **custom formula**?

Comment: Please `DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.—copy or type the text into the question.` [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @cnavar Either are fine