# How to identify what currency is in cell?

Tags: regex, google-sheets, match, locale, vlookup

I need function what will return currency type of cell property. Is it possible?

[image: What I expect]

I found only `=TYPE(cell)` method what return only data type (number, string etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there isn't such a function. you will need to try something like:

```
 =INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(REGEXREPLACE(TO_TEXT(A1:A3), "[0-9, ]", ), 
  {"$", "USD"; "€", "EUR"; "zł", "PLN"}, 2, 0)))
```

also, you may want to see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73767719/locale-differences-in-google-sheets-documentation-missing-pages

[image]

Comment: Your suggest looks perfectly but parse error, and I still trying to fix that.

Comment: @AndreiPrystupchyk `=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(REGEXREPLACE(TO_TEXT(A1:A3); "[0-9, ]"; ); 
  {"$"\ "USD"; "€"\ "EUR"; "zł"\ "PLN"}; 2; 0)))`