# Changing Date format in Google Sheets

Tags: regex, date, datetime, google-sheets, locale

I have copy pasted data from an Excel file into Google Sheet.
One of the columns has date formatted as - 11-07-2022.
[image]

Google Sheets is reading it as 11th July, 2022 - whereas I want it to read as 7th Nov, 2022.
While I can just change the format manually in one of the cells, unfortunately I have more than 1000 rows with such date format.

Is there a better way to do it? I searched online and no matter how I changed the format, it only changed the way the date is displayed rather than reading the date as MM-DD-YYYY.

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see: [stackoverflow.com/questions/73767719/locale-differences-in-google-sheets-documentation-missing-pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73767719/locale-differences-in-google-sheets-documentation-missing-pages)

[image]

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(REGEXREPLACE(TO_TEXT(A2:A), 
 "(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d{2,4})", "$2/$1/$3")*1, A2:A)*1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

IF you know a coding language, you can write a quick script to take the current dates and re-order the parts to put them into the MM-DD-YYYY order.

Comment: I do know javascript a little bit. Can you guide what is the exact script I need to add in Gscript, I can give it a try.

Comment: @MayankAgarwal looks like the answer above should do the trick, let me know if it doesn't and you want some help with the javascript route