# How to stack multiple columns into one, alternating rows - Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, syntax, spreadsheet, flatten

I'm working on a Google Sheets document that has data stacked in columns in an unusual order (see image for reference)

I have what you see on columns `A`, `B` and `C`. But I want what I have on column `E`.
I have 8 pages with hundreds of data elements, all sorted in 3 columns like that and I'm looking for a formula or a custom script that would allow me to arrange the data in the right sequence.

I did research trying to find a solution, but none of the ones I found work well for this situation. The order of the elements is very important.

[image]

---

**EDIT:
The data is not numbers. It's text. So sorting formulas wouldn't work, because it would sort it alphabetically and it would mess up the order**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

all you need is:

```
=FLATTEN(A1:C7)
```

with open ranges you can do:

```
=QUERY(FLATTEN(A1:C); "where Col1 is not null"; )
```

see: **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73767719/**

[image]

Comment: For some reason, flatten didn't seem to work for me before! This solved the issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
=SORT(ARRAYFORMULA(FLATTEN(A1:A,B1:B,C1:C)),1,1)
```

- 

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I just added an edit to the question. The data is actually text, not numbers. So this formula sorts it alphabetically and it messes up the order.