# Google sheets: How to add a helper row to fill gaps in a list of customer ID row

Tags: loops, google-sheets, lambda, vlookup, offset

I'm trying to figure out a way how to fill blank cells in a row with previous existing data. I have an array of data with a customer ID-key I'd need to copy to some lines that don't automatically have the key ID due to gaps in source data.

Here's the situation. Gaps in data in Columns A:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 |
|  | Cell 4 |
|  | Cell 6 |
| Cell 7 | Cell 8 |
|  | Cell 10 |
|  | Cell 12 |

This question comes in two parts. See the wished solution I tried to create below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B2:B="",, VLOOKUP(ROW(A2:A), IF(A2:A<>"", {ROW(A2:A), A2:A}), 2, 1)))
```

[image]

---

### update:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B2:B="";; VLOOKUP(ROW(A2:A); IF(A2:A<>""; {ROW(A2:A)\ A2:A}); 2; 1)))
```

or:

```
=SCAN(; A2:INDEX(A:A; MAX(ROW(B:B)*(B:B<>""))); LAMBDA(a; b; IF(b=""; a; b)))
```

---

see: **[stackoverflow.com/questions/73767719](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73767719/)**

[image]

Comment: That's it!

This seems like working solution, yet I don't seem to get it working. I thought to add that extra column on the left side of the original A column, but I guess it's not relevant where the helper column is located. 
I try to figure this syntax out. Due to scandinavian input settings my google sheets syntax uses semicolon instead of commas.

Comment: Yeah, there's a bug in the translation of the locale settings. You should change {ROW(A2:A), A2:A} with {ROW(A2:A)\A2:A}

Comment: @Coach_Arto answer updated. use 2nd formula

Comment: Thanks a ton! This solved it. Now it's working and I could modify the formula to my needs. Boggles my mind though, how fast you came up with the solution. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Use [**SCAN**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12569094?hl=en), like this

```
=SCAN(,A2:A7,LAMBDA(a,c,IF(c="",a,c)))
```

[image]

Since this is a very common question, I had also created a named function `_FILL` that solves this problem. You can import it from [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ej1POoWMmRYLsv-3X6iZTURVMy_-D4cqBNsHs1oS5kw/edit#gid=0).

And use it like this:

```
_FILL(vector, fill_mode) 

// fill with previous non-empty -> fill_mode = 1
// fill with next non-empty -> fill_mode = -1
```

```
_FILL(A2:A7,1)
```

[image]