# Google Sheets Quartile Function Giving Error

Tags: google-sheets, statistics, dataset, quartile

In Google sheets I write the formula `=QUARTILE(G7:G27, 1)` to give the lower quartile between G7 and G27 but it gives me `#ERROR`!

Here is a print screen that shows my problem.

[image]

Comment: Changing the comma with a semicolon? Seeing your language, you'll probably need it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `;` as fx argument separator:

```
=QUARTILE(G7:G27; 1)
```

see (not): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73767719/locale-differences-in-google-sheets-documentation-missing-pages

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In the event your spreadsheet locale uses commas `,` as decimal separators, you will have to use semicolons `;` as formula argument separators, like this:

```
=quartile(G7:G27; 1)
```