# Using QUERY on Google Sheet returning "Formula parse error"

Tags: google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, sumifs, google-query-language

Writing a Google Sheet for personal expenses I am trying to create a query to sum the expenses of a type, but the editor is retrieving a parse error that I can't achieve the logs (not sure it is possible).

Please consider only rows below row 15.

On Cell B9 I'd like to sum every expense of type **Saúde**. Can you help me understand what I am doing wrong?

D column represents the amount of the expense.

C column represents the type of the expense.

Query: `=QUERY(C16:C1000,"select sum(D) where C = 'Saúde'")`

[image]

(Plus) Curiosity apart: is possible to set up the sheet to write some rows and then the sheet push below rows to beneath then I could write the data ever on the top instead at the last row bottom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=QUERY(C16:D1000; "select sum(D) where C = 'Saúde'"; )
```

see (not): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73767719/locale-differences-in-google-sheets-documentation-missing-pages

[image]

Comment: Once did it, the error goes away but I am seeing only the string "sum" instead the sum of the values, on the cell.

Comment: Update: I realized that the query's result value has written below row, how to put the query's value on the same row I typed the query?

Comment: @Augusto use: `=QUERY(C16:D1000; "select sum(D) where C = 'Saúde' label sum(D)''"; )`