how to QUERY by column name (label, header, variable) in google sheets
As per (poor) google's official QUERY documentation here we can filter our tables by referencing individual columns, for example like:
=QUERY(A:I; "select A,B where D > 9000"; 1)

this may be sufficient for small-scale projects where we either use simple or more advanced queries to extract data we need, however, in case we would have a massive lookup table (like 50+ columns) and we would need to filter-down multiple smaller tables in rapid succession (with no intention to store them) is there some way how we could query more easily? for example, directly by column headers / labels (avoiding remembering column numbers/positions and triple checking if 47th column is really the right one)
quick search reveals there was already an attempt to achieve this with BETTERQUERY, but I would be interested in a simpler alternative (for less tech-savvy populus)
is there some alternative way to query, maybe with some universal formula that could translate various instances and variations, like the example below, with ease?
=QUERY(A:I; "select <name>,<email> where <sales> > 9000"; 1)


officially, there are two sources of documentation:

mentioned QUERY function/formula

and QUERY language reference


unfortunately, both of them are poor, and QUERY formula is a function probably with the most undocumented features (bugs) out there. there are only two variants of syntax:

if range is an active reference, the syntax of 2nd QUERY parameter accepts column letters as input:
=QUERY(A:C; "select B,A"; )

if range is an construct (of arrays or another formula), the syntax of 2nd QUERY parameter accepts only Col references as input:
=QUERY({A:C}, "select Col2,Col1", )
=QUERY({A:A, B:C}, "select Col2,Col1", )
=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("id", "Sheet1!A:C")}, "select Col2,Col1", )
=QUERY(INDIRECT("Sheet1!A:C"), "select Col2,Col1", )


for locale differences (when to use \ instead of ,) and how to convert any formula syntax to non-english semicolon ; version, refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73767720/5632629
fun fact: since 2024 we are allowed (this was previously not possible) to use Col references without wrapping simple range reference into array brackets { }.


side notes for QUERY rookies:

the 2nd QUERY parameter has its own ecosystem. in there, do not use semicolons ; nor backslashes \ as column/item separators - only commas ,
=QUERY(A:C; "select B,C"; 0)

it's a good practice to not forget the 3rd QUERY parameter, even if you don't need it. you can use 0 or leave it blank like:
=QUERY(A:C; "select B,C"; )

and if your dataset is mixed (eg. column contains numeric values formatted as numbers and text strings formatted as plain text) QUERY contains a bug (not a feature) manifesting in a particular way - QUERY will take over and make self-assumption, that you don't need the minority of that column's data, and it will show you only the majority of dataset. in 99% of cases, this is not a desired outcome that the user wishes, so in order to not "loose" the data, this needs to be combated either via internal formatting of the particular column or more drastically by forceful conversion of whole or partial range into plain text (in various ways) based on needed scenario. for example:
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({A:A, TO_TEXT(B:B), C:C}), "select Col2,Col3", 1))



now to answer the question - yes, there is an alternative how to select columns based on the table headers (of course dynamically, not by hard-coding it into formula). this setup will require some helper fields for sake of convenience and speed.
this is an example of TURBOQUERY concept, version 1.0 (feel free to edit it in ways to fit your needs. as of now, no plans in motion to release v2.0 so if you significantly improve it you are welcome to share it)

Sheet1:

Sheet2:

the only formula from B12:
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(LET(xx, Sheet1!A:Z, 
 select, B3:B9, where, C3:C9, logic, D3:D9, sortby, E3:E9, order, F3:F9, 
 r, REGEXREPLACE(where, "(?i)(?:^\(.?not )|(?:^\( )|(?:^not )|(<|>|=|!|is (?:not )?null|matches|contains|starts|ends).*", ), QUERY({xx}, 
 "select "&IF(SUM(LEN(select))=0, "*", TEXTJOIN(",", 1, IFNA("Col"&MATCH(select, INDEX(xx, 1), ))))&
 " where 1=1 "&IF(SUM(LEN(where))=0,,TRIM(TEXTJOIN(, 1, IF((logic="")*(where<>""),
 " AND ", " "&logic&" ")&IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(where, "\(not|\( not|not|\("))&IFNA(" Col"&MATCH(TRIM(r), INDEX(xx, 1), ))&" "&REGEXEXTRACT(where, r&"(.*)"))))&IF(SUM(LEN(sortby))=0,,
 " order by "&TEXTJOIN(",", 1, IFNA("Col"&MATCH(sortby, INDEX(xx, 1), ))&IF((sortby<>"")*(order<>""), " "&order&" ", ) )), 1)), "syntax error"))

data validation:

ranges B3:B9 and E3:E9 are dropdowns fed from Sheet1!1:1 row (headers)
range D4:D9 is a dropdown list with OR item only
range F3:F9 is a dropdown list with DESC item only

spreadsheet demo copy

what is supported (also included in notes):

supports SELECT parameter

supports WHERE parameter

supports OR/AND logic gates

supports SORT BY parameter

supports ORDER BY parameter

SELECT fields can be left empty to get the whole table

SELECT fields can accept only valid header names

header names can be case-insensitive

WHERE fields can be left empty if no conditions are needed

WHERE fields can accept only valid header names followed (or preceded) by valid syntax conditions

WHERE fields support these conditions:

> 
< 
>= 
<= 
!= 
<> 
= 
not (preceded) 
is null 
is not null 
matches (supports regex) 
contains 
starts with 
ends with


conditions can be case-insensitive

parentheses are supported too for OR hierarchy, but opening ( need to be followed by space

numbers formatted as plain text and text needs to be single-quoted as by standard

supports regex commands after matches condition

within LOGIC fields, AND logic is set by default

within LOGIC fields, override with OR logic is possible if needed

LOGIC fields are bound with WHERE fields and offset by 1 row down

if WHERE fields contain only one entry OR logic should not be used

SORT BY fields can be left empty if no sorting is needed

SORT BY fields can accept only valid header names

header names can be case-insensitive

within ORDER fields, ASC-ending order is set by default

within ORDER fields, override with DESC-ending order is possible if needed

ORDER fields are bound with SORT BY fields



suggested improvements for v2.0:

better regex patterns within REGEXREPLACE part of the formula
extended support for more conditions (like like, date...)
extended support for more clauses (like limit, offset, format, pivot, label, group by)
adding support for arithmetic (+, -, ×, ÷) capabilities
adding support for aggregating capabilities (avg, max, min, count, sum)
adding support for scalar functions (like year, month, day, upper, lower...)
adding more fail-safes for exotic header names and much more
everything is possible!


few words about formula:
not really much to say. it is a simple, lightweight formula that takes input fields and auto-assembles the query string dynamically based on a pre-defined ruleset and a few fail safes. nothing special. the main idea is to build a generator. row with headers is transformed into dropdown menu, and then simple MATCH fx looks for the correct column of invoked selection, and transforms it into Col number reference. this way the end-user is able to generate various tables/reports without constantly fiddling with QUERY formula itself, and due to its "friendliness" even user with no formulae skill will be happy and able to interact with a dataset (win-win with grandma-proof stamp). few other generator examples:

QUERY formula generation
array of IMPORTRANGE generation
dynamic sheet name generation
alternative sheet name generation
simple range generation
simple string generation
get dynamically array of ranges from multiple sheets

