Google Spreadsheet time format changed when "Minute" is between 1 to 12
Here is the link to the spreadsheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IKtSgeneUy5esKV9dIk_cEbMKm1vda5YpCqMo279k04/edit?usp=sharing
my time format is HH:MM:SS, but when i input time with its "Minute" range between 1 to 12, it automatically change my time format to date format (DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS), and it reads as 0:00:00
For example :
08.29.40    08.29.40
08.31.29    08.31.29
17.31.43    17.31.43
17.35.24    17.35.24
17.36.52    17.36.52
09.02.10    0:00:00 (Notice that the minute is "2")
I want it to stay with time format, instead of changed to date format.

your locale is set to Indonesia:

the correct format for Indonesian date, time and datetime is:

in your A column you are entering your time with dots . instead of colons :
this way you are actually entering dates not times. to enter time on your locale use colons : like:

see more at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73767720/5632629
