Why is the search function keep failing in text book example
So i try to check if a substring is in a string using search has advised by the documentation.
I keep receiving the '#ERROR' error (Formula Analysis Error) even for text book example !
=SEARCH( "Hello", "Hello, there!" )

I test another new sheet it does the same but if i do so on another sheet i use has inspiration (not created by me) it does work !
So i'm at a lost to understand where the issue came from, i suppose this a parameter issue but i have no clue how to fix it.

see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73767720/5632629

Most likely your sheet locale uses semi-colon convention; try with:
=search( "Hello"; "Hello, there!" )


Thank you for your quick response, indeed that was the cause of the issue, I knew that they do change the function names but I didn't think there was a difference between ';' And ','...
