Pivot Filter in sheets for the last 12 Months
i have a google sheets table with 4 Colums. One Column is the dates entry in Form (Year/ Month/ Day "2024/05/01").
Also i have a pivot table where i want to filter the table.
I want to filter the last 12 Months automaticaly.
How does it work, which formula i had to write in the pivot?
So, that is a sample Data



Date
Category
amount




2023-01-01
1
1


2023-02-01
1
1


2023-03-01
3
1


2023-04-01
1
1


2023-05-01
2
1


2023-06-01
3
1


2023-07-01
2
1


2023-08-01
3
1


2023-10-01
2
1


2023-11-01
2
1


2023-12-01
3
1


2024-01-01
2
1


2024-02-01
3
1


2024-03-01
2
1


2024-04-01
2
1


2024-05-01
3
1



What i want is, to pivot the table, that the sum of the last 12Month are dynamicly shown. (in this month its 2023-05-01 to 2024-04-31)
In this case the output should show this:



Category:
Amount:




1
0


2
7


3
5



tried several formulas.

update:
The query obove is with one range (Table1 A2:C19)
But there is another table in the sheet. (Table2 E2:F5). In this range there is in  column A the Categorys from above (1,2,3), and in the second Column B there are the real names from Column A (Audi, BMW, Volvo)
Now i want to optimize the query above that there is the wording of Tabel 2 written instead of the Categorys. (BMW instead of "2")


Use QUERY() function.

How is the formular.? That´s the key point.

Post few sample data and show your desired output.

try filter by condition: is between:
=EOMONTH(TODAY(), -13)+1

and:
=TODAY()


you can even use:
=EDATE(TODAY(), -12)


but better is to use standalone QUERY instead of buggy pivot table:
=QUERY(A1:C, "select Col2,sum(Col3) 
              where Col1 >= date '"&TEXT(EOMONTH(TODAY(), -13)+1, "e-m-d")&"' 
                and Col1 <= now() 
              group by Col2")



={"Category:", "Amount:"; SORTN({QUERY(A2:C, 
 "select Col2,sum(Col3) 
  where Col1 >= date '"&TEXT(EOMONTH(TODAY(), -13)+1, "e-m-d")&"' 
    and Col1 <= now() 
  group by Col2
  label sum(Col3)''"); FILTER({B2:B, IFNA(0/B2:B, 0)}, B2:B<>"")}, 9^9, 2, 1, 1)}



update 1:
=INDEX({"Category:", "Amount:"; LET(a, A2:A, b, VLOOKUP(B2:B, E1:F3, 2, 0), c, C2:C, 
 SORTN({QUERY({a, b, c}, 
 "select Col2,sum(Col3) 
  where Col1 >= date '"&TEXT(EOMONTH(TODAY(), -13)+1, "e-m-d")&"' 
    and Col1 <= now() 
  group by Col2
  label sum(Col3)''"); FILTER({b, IFERROR(0/b, 0)}, b<>"")}, 9^9, 2, 1, 1))})


update 2:
=INDEX({"Category:"\ "Amount:"; LET(a; A2:A; b; VLOOKUP(B2:B; E1:F3; 2; 0); c; C2:C; 
 SORTN({QUERY({a\ b\ c}; 
 "select Col2,sum(Col3) 
  where Col1 >= date '"&TEXT(EOMONTH(TODAY(); -13)+1; "e-m-d")&"' 
    and Col1 <= now() 
  group by Col2
  label sum(Col3)''"); FILTER({b\ IFERROR(0/b; 0)}; b<>"")}; 9^9; 2; 1; 1))})

update 3:
=QUERY(INDEX({"Category:"\ "Amount:"; LET(a; A2:A; b; 
 IFNA(VLOOKUP(B2:B; E1:F3; 2; 0)); c; C2:C; 
 SORTN({QUERY({a\ b\ c}; 
 "select Col2,sum(Col3) 
  where Col1 >= date '"&TEXT(EOMONTH(TODAY(); -13)+1; "e-m-d")&"' 
    and Col1 <= now() 
  group by Col2
  label sum(Col3)''"); FILTER({b\ IFERROR(0/b; 0)}; b<>"")}; 9^9; 2; 1; 1))}); 
 "where Col2>0 and Col1 is not null"; 1)


wow. the Formula in the pivot table works fine! THX a lot! Now i will test the query. Why is it better to use query instead of Pivot? Isn´t there much more Code to write and to know?

@Mario it may be "more code" but it is all in one place. sql syntax is not so hard https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage and overall it is more versatile than pivot tables

I see that there is much more potential with query. The query-code you posted works also, after some adjustments (in my real table). But, there is another problem in this case: I have a second table. in this table there is the category from above ( 1,2,3) and the real name (e.g. Audi, BMW, Volvo). How is it posible to get the real name in the query?

@playerO . I edit your last answer, because i had a problem again.

@Mario see Update 2. and see https://stackoverflow.com/a/73767720/5632629 how to convert properly english locale to non-english one

@playerO perfect! it works. Many, many thanks to you! TOP

@playerO if in Column B one ore more cells are empty, there comes #NA in the resutl. How can the Filter be customised?

@Mario wrap VLOOKUP into IFNA

@playerO that works, but there es another Row, with "0" in the Column "Amount", and with no Category. I think it could be the sum of no entries in the Categorie-Column.?

@Mario and you want to remove it? or what is your ask?

yes. i don´t want it in the result. And now there is one more issue . If the first row has no entries, in the result there is a clear row in first place.

@Mario can you share a copy/sample of your sheet? or try update 3

it seams that i could not share, or do other things, except add comments. !? btw The query update works so long. The problems from my previous post seem to be solved. But one thing remains. When there is no entrie vom e.g. Category 2 then the Category 2 with quantity "0" should also be in the result, but it isn´t. the Row isn´t there.

Do you have a solution? The linked sheet form you isn´t there anymore.

@Mario sorry, I was under assumption that this is already solved... here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1i5TIb5GbdCJpRPo9aVGUzfrkyyRRzPyAMJVPuwIH82A/edit#gid=991008080
